# Different format RavenDB IDs on clustered server

Tags: ravendb

We have a DotNet Core API (C#) on AWS with clustered RavenDB servers (5.23). When documents are created then the Id has a different format depending on the client. If using Swagger/Postman/xUnit Test then we get Id="person/1234-C". If a third party calls the endpoint then we get Id="Person/0000000000000001234-C". Note that the first character is lowercase in one and uppercase in the other. The person.Id (string) property is set to null before the entity is saved.

There is no custom configuration of the Id formats. The only convention set is MaxNumberOfRequestsPerSession. I've read the docs on Ids (Server Id/Identity) but I haven't seen anything useful.

Why is the Id format different? How can I ensure that it's always the correct format? Would a client and AWS in different countries with different languages (but same timezone) have any impact somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [this](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.2/csharp/server/kb/document-identifier-generation) article ?

Format `Person/0000000000000001234-C` is generated by the server
See [**Server-Side ID**](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.2/csharp/server/kb/document-identifier-generation#server-side-id)

Format `person/1234-C` can be generated by both the server & the client
See [**Hilo Algorithm**](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.2/csharp/server/kb/document-identifier-generation#hilo-algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

RanenDB id is case insensitive.
But it doesn't change the case.
If you set a specific id RavenDB will use it as is.

The short id ("person/1234-C") typically comes from Hilo
If you use Hilo to generate the id you have multiple ways to control the prefix.

1. you can register id convention - https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/faq/client-api/configuration/identifier-generation/type-specific
2. You can change the find collection name convention - https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.2/csharp/client-api/session/configuration/how-to-customize-collection-assignment-for-entities

The long id ("Person/0000000000000001234-C") typically comes from the server
To use server-side you store the document with a prefix like "Person/" (or "person/" and RavenDB keeps the case).

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.0/csharp/server/kb/document-identifier-generation
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/faq/client-api/configuration/identifier-generation/global

https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/discussions/13111

```
class TestObj
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
class TestObj3
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

class TestObj2
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Prop { get; set; }
}

[Fact]
public async Task TestCase()
{
    using var store = GetDocumentStore(new Options
    {
        ModifyDocumentStore = s =>
        {
            s.Conventions.FindCollectionName = t => t == typeof(TestObj) ? t.Name.ToLower() : null;
            s.Conventions.RegisterAsyncIdConvention<TestObj2>((s1, class2) => Task.FromResult($"testClass2/{class2.Prop}"));
        }
    });
    using (var session = store.OpenAsyncSession())
    {
        var testObj = new TestObj();
        await session.StoreAsync(testObj); // "testobj/1-A"

        var testObj2 = new TestObj2{Prop = "Something"}; 
        await session.StoreAsync(testObj2); // "testClass2/Something"
        
        var testObj3 = new TestObj3();
        await session.StoreAsync(testObj3); // "TestObj3s/1-A"
        
        var testObj4 = new TestObj3();
        await session.StoreAsync(testObj4, "TestObj/"); // "TestObj/0000000000000000006-A"
        
        var testObj5 = new TestObj3();
        await session.StoreAsync(testObj5, "testobj/"); // "TestObj/0000000000000000006-A"
        
        await session.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do I need to do so that it always uses the correct format? Is Server Id the correct format for our cluster? We use the default server behavior whatever that is. Why isn't the default server behavior always Server Id in a cluster? There are no conventions. The entity Id property is set to null before saving. Is the only way to get the 'correct' format to have a convention for every document type in our system?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "correct format". You can use any method you want. If you want consistency you should use the same method all over your system.

Comment: I assumed that there would be a technical benefit to using one format over another with regards to clustering. i.e. A recommended format for clustering. I appreciate that the docs mentions that some formats are recommended where doing a lot of bulk inserts but we don't many bulk inserts.

Comment: Both formats are designed for clustering by adding the node tag that generates it.